# Android Count records in SQL database

Tags: android, sql, count

On Start of my app im trying to get it to toast the number of records in my database

In my Main Activity I tried

```
    final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();  
    Cursor c = db.getAsset3(null);
    int Counter=c.getCount();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Counter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

and in my DBHelper I have the following method

```
     public Cursor getAsset3(Editable strname) throws SQLException 
     { 
     Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from DATABASE_TABLE",null); 
     return mCursor;                           
     }
```

the app keeps crashes on start

any ideas where im going wrong

any help appreciated

Mark

Comment: Now i have a sql error if i use a standard query like db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_FAULTREF}, KEY_FAULTREF + "='" + "102092"+ "'", null,null, null, null, null); it returns 1 which is correct but if i use the select statement db.rawQuery("select * from DATABASE_TABLE",null);  the app crashes

Comment: See my answer,and please write new question for new problem.

Comment: Ok Fixed it used db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null); and it gives correct total many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Counter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(Counter), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Because you want to display `int` in `makeText`,caste it to `String`.
For more info see [Android Toast makeText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29)

**Edit**

And change your query like

```
 Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE,null);
```

Where `DATABASE_TABLE` is the name of your table.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your Toast.

Instead of below:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Counter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Replace below code:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Counter+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```